# Decreased training speed on multi-GPU machine with dynamic RNN of Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have two machines available on which I can train models built with Tensorflow: a local desktop machine with one GPU (called "local" in the following) and a remote cluster with 4 GPUs (called "cluster" in the following). Even though the cluster has 4 GPUs I'm only using one GPU at a time (e.g. through `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2 python script.py`). My problem is that training the exact same model on the cluster is considerably slower than on my local machine, even though the cluster has more powerful GPUs. I realize that this question might be very localized and it is difficult to find out why this is the case, however I am at loss as to what causes this behavior. In the following I try to give as many details about the configuration of both machines and the model I'm building.

### Model

The model is a simple toy RNN taken from [this github](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/) project. The model definition is as follows:

```
# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
training_steps = 600
batch_size = 128
display_step = 200

# Network Parameters
seq_max_len = 20  # Sequence max length
n_hidden = 64  # hidden layer num of features
n_classes = 2  # linear sequence or not

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, seq_max_len, 1])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])
# A placeholder for indicating each sequence length
seqlen = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

# Define weights
weights = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_classes]))
    }
biases = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
    }


def dynamicRNN(x, seqlen, weights, biases):
    # Prepare data shape to match `rnn` function requirements
    # Current data input shape: (batch_size, n_steps, n_input)
    # Required shape: 'n_steps' tensors list of shape (batch_size, n_input)

    with tf.device('gpu:0'):
        # Unstack to get a list of 'n_steps' tensors of shape (batch_size, n_input)
        x = tf.unstack(x, seq_max_len, 1)

        # Define a lstm cell with tensorflow
        lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden)

        # Get lstm cell output, providing 'sequence_length' will perform dynamic
        # calculation.
        outputs, states = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32,
                                                    sequence_length=seqlen)

        # When performing dynamic calculation, we must retrieve the last
        # dynamically computed output, i.e., if a sequence length is 10, we need
        # to retrieve the 10th output.
        # However TensorFlow doesn't support advanced indexing yet, so we build
        # a custom op that for each sample in batch size, get its length and
        # get the corresponding relevant output.

        # 'outputs' is a list of output at every timestep, we pack them in a Tensor
        # and change back dimension to [batch_size, n_step, n_input]
        outputs = tf.stack(outputs)
        outputs = tf.transpose(outputs, [1, 0, 2])

        # Hack to build the indexing and retrieve the right output.
        batch_size = tf.shape(outputs)[0]
        # Start indices for each sample
        index = tf.range(0, batch_size)*seq_max_len+(seqlen-1)
        # Indexing
        outputs = tf.gather(tf.reshape(outputs, [-1, n_hidden]), index)

        # Linear activation, using outputs computed above
        return tf.matmul(outputs, weights['out'])+biases['out']


pred = dynamicRNN(x, seqlen, weights, biases)

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Evaluate model
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
```

The complete (runnable) python script can be found here: https://pastebin.com/LnKmCiSy

### Configuration on local

- Tensorflow: v1.3 (pre-compiled version installed)
- CUDA: v8.0.61
- cuDNN: v6.0.21
- GPU: GeForce GTX TITAN X
- NVIDIA Driver: 375.82
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04, 64-bit

### Configuration on cluster

Exactly the same as for local, except:

- GPU: GeForce GTX TITAN X Pascal
- NVIDIA Driver: 375.66

### Performance Measures

Executing the above provided toy script I get the following outputs on local:

```
Step 128, Minibatch Loss= 0.725320, Training Accuracy= 0.43750, Time: 0.3180224895477295
Step 25600, Minibatch Loss= 0.683126, Training Accuracy= 0.50962, Time: 0.013816356658935547
Step 51200, Minibatch Loss= 0.680907, Training Accuracy= 0.50000, Time: 0.013682842254638672
Step 76800, Minibatch Loss= 0.677346, Training Accuracy= 0.57692, Time: 0.014072895050048828
```

And the following on the cluster:

```
Step 128, Minibatch Loss= 1.536499, Training Accuracy= 0.47656, Time: 0.8308820724487305
Step 25600, Minibatch Loss= 0.693901, Training Accuracy= 0.49038, Time: 0.06193065643310547
Step 51200, Minibatch Loss= 0.689709, Training Accuracy= 0.53846, Time: 0.05762457847595215
Step 76800, Minibatch Loss= 0.685955, Training Accuracy= 0.54808, Time: 0.06454324722290039
```

As you can see, execution times on the cluster are about 4x higher. I tried to profile what is happening on the GPU through the use of the timeline feature. I find it difficult to interpret the output of this feature, but what I found most striking is that there are huge idle gaps on the cluster. For this, see the following images that show a trace of the timeline feature for one call to `sess.run` (note that the scale of the time axis is not exactly the same in both images, but the difference should still be visible).

Timeline on cluster:
[image: Profile on cluster]

Timeline on local:
[image: Profile on local]

Did any of you observe the same behavior? What are possible reasons that could cause this behavior and/or how can if further narrow down the issue?

Comment: Wait, which timeline trace is local and which is cluster?

Comment: @Engineero Ups, forgot about that, added titles now.